# Создать двумерный динамический массив с произвольным количеством элементов в каждой строке

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Как можно создать двумерный динамический массив с произвольным количеством элементов в каждой строке?

Comment: Уточните - именно *массив*? И что означает * с произвольным количеством элементов в каждой строке* - в каждой строке при этом одно и то же количество элементов (прямоугольная матрица) или оно может быть разным?

Comment: В каждой строке может быть разное количество элементов

Answer (score 4):

А по моему - когда речь идет о "произвольном количестве элементов в каждой строке", то термин "произвольный" надо понимать так: "в каждой строке может быть сколько хочешь элементов".

Такую задачу решает уже "вектор векторов":

```
    vector<vector<int>> arr;
```

Comment: ну почему обязательно вектор?  С массивами никак?... И даже вектор не может содержать сколько угодно элементов, если память недостаточна.

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<vector<int> > vect{ { 1, 2, 3 }, 
                               { 4, 5, 6 }, 
                               { 7, 8, 9 } };
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз в каждой строке может быть разное количество элементов...

Вариант первый, скорее С'шный. Именно динамический массив. Например, 4 строки, длины строк - 5, 2, 3, 8.

```
int ** arr = new int*[4];
arr[0] = new int[5];
arr[1] = new int[2];
arr[2] = new int[3];
arr[3] = new int[8];
```

Все. Минусы - надо помнить размеры (длины строк), их довольно сложно менять - для этого надо создать новую строку с требуемым размером, перекопировать в нее нужные элементы, изменить указатель на строку, удалить исходную...

Вариант второй - использование векторов.

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(4);
arr[0].resize(5);
arr[1].resize(2);
arr[2].resize(3);
arr[3].resize(8);
```

Здесь все гораздо удобнее. Во-первых, каждая строка знает свой размер, `arr` знает, сколько в нем строк. Изменить размер легко - просто `resize()`, или, если его надо увеличить на 1 элемент - `push_back()`.

В обоих вариантах работает обращение c двумя индексами `arr[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

Произвольное количество элементов настораживает. Тут лучше учесть, что может не хватить памяти для заданного числа элементов, и обработать этот случай некоторым образом:

```
size_t row;
cin >> row;
int** p = new int*[row];
size_t i{}, size{};
cout << "вводим размеры массивов\n";
try {
    while (i < row) {
        cin >> size;
        size += 100;
        p[i] = new int[size];
        ++i;
    }
}
catch (std::bad_alloc)
{
    //...
    std::cerr << "не хватило памяти для  " << i <<" _ ой строки";
} 
//....
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2023032/13970074 и `std::` для `size_t`

Comment: @dIm0n,  это не значит,что динамические массивы нельзя использовать.  2) ::size_t определяется в заголовке обратной совместимости stddef.h. Он был частью ANSI/ISO C и ISO C++ с самого начала. Каждая реализация С++ должна поставляться с stddef.h (совместимостью) и cstddef. Так что  size_t  и есть  std::size_t.  У вас неплохие знания, но  не полные,так что будьте добры иногда обсуждать  а не утверждать.

Comment: Вы не привели используемые заголовочные файлы. В C++ обычно используют cstddef, а не stddef.h, и там нужен `std::` (https://stackoverflow.com/q/5813700/13970074), а первая ссылка не про массивы, а про то, как исключения ловить

Comment: @dIm0n, ну с вами бесполезно что то обсуждать. Я уже ответил.  Как исключение ловить?... Ну спасибо, не знал.  А в чем ошибка в моем коде? Может просто скажете, а не будете все время ссылаться на чье то мнение или на документацию? Я не стал  просматривать по ссылке.   Что используют в C++ программах, это дело хозяйское. Никто не запрещает использовать  только  файлы с расширением. Но вы прочли невнимательно или не поняли.